# Shorthand for instantiation and initialization using an extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Is there any shorthand for using an extension method to instantiate and initialise an object?

My aim is to abstract-away and encapsulate the code required to instantiate and initialise an instance of MyType suitable for unit testing.

Example:

```
//...
//convoluted client code - I'd like to avoid the null instance creation
MyType t = null;
t = t.GetTestInstance();
//...

//extension method
public static class MyTypeExtensions
{
  public static MyType GetTestInstance(this MyType t)
  {
    var ctorInjectedDependency = blah;

    return new MyType(ctorInjectedDependency);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am beginning to think this is all a very bad idea. I'll leave the question open in case, anyone has any pertinent experience.

Comment: We have considered doing a feature called "extension constructors" which would basically be a way to encode the factory pattern more nicely in the language. However it has never been high enough priority to actually design or implement it. If you have a really awesome scenario for it I'd be happy to pass it along to the design team the next time this comes up for debate. (Which might be a long time from now...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will suit your needs:

```
public class MyType
{
  public MyType(string s)
  {
    Property = s;
  }

  public string Property { get; set; }
}

public static class MyTypeExtensions
{
  public static object GetTestInstance(this Type t)
  {
    var ctorInjectedDependency = "blah";
    var ctorInfo = t.GetConstructor(new[]{typeof(string)});

    return ctorInfo.Invoke(new object[] {ctorInjectedDependency});
  }

  public static T GetTestInstance<T>(this Type t)
  {
    var ctorInjectedDependency = "blah";
    var ctorInfo = t.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });

    return (T)ctorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { ctorInjectedDependency });
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var my = typeof(MyType).GetTestInstance(); // maybe just object is enough
var my2 = typeof(MyType).GetTestInstance<MyType>();


Console.WriteLine((my as MyType).Property);
Console.WriteLine(my2.Property);
```